# Status nil when seeding database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to seed my Rails application using a seed file. Everything works, except the `status` attribute of my Order object that's always `nil`.

#### seed.rb

```
Order.destroy_all
1000.times do
  Order.create!(
    product: products.sample,
    customer: Customer.all.sample,
    status: Order.statuses.keys.map(&:to_sym).sample
  )
end
```

#### order.rb

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :customer

  enum status: [:draft, :confirmed, :canceled]
end
```

Comment: Try `Order.create(status: Order.statuses.values.sample.to_s)` if you get an `ArgumentError: '#' is not a valid status` error, then you don't have the proper data type for your `status` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) `status` column must be an `integer`. I guess you have `string` instead, so `status` always resets to `nil`.

Comment: That doesn't help either `Order.statuses.values.sample`

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work. I recommend you to give a try in the Rails Console first, to see if there is something wrong. Here is what i got trying to reproduce your error:

Model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    enum status: [:draft, :confirmed, :canceled]
end
```

Console output:

```
2.2.1 :004 > Order.statuses.keys.map(&:to_sym).sample
    => :confirmed
```

---

UPDATE: Here is my test generating seeds:

**db/seeds.rb:**

```
Order.destroy_all
    1000.times do
    Order.create!(
        status: Order.statuses.keys.map(&:to_sym).sample
    )
end
```

After execute `rake db:seed` i went to the console and checked status values of the generated data:

```
2.2.1 :023 > Order.where('orders.status = ?', 
    Order.statuses['confirmed']).size
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE (orders.status = 1)
 => 324
```

Here is another status:

```
2.2.1 :024 > Order.where('orders.status = ?', 
Order.statuses['draft']).size
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE (orders.status = 0)
 => 340
```

Comment: What is the type of your column status?

Comment: I made a test here using the type `integer` and the seed generated data without any problem.

Comment: The problem was that I had status as a string instead of an integer.